# How come this relative positioned div is displayed differently in IE?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a relative positioned div inside another div. The inside-div is positioned with percentage (left: 0%; top:13%).

My problem is that in all IE versions the div is displayed some pixels further down than where it is displayed in Chrome, or FF...

Anybody recognize this?

```
   <div class="nav_container" id="nav_container">
   <div id="nav_container2" style="position: relative; left: 0%; top: 13%;"></div>
   </div>
```

Also, I am just about to browser adjust my website so some article about most common problems with IE is appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Here is the style for the primary div.

```
.nav_container {
    background-image: url(../Graphics/menu_lvl1.gif);
    height: 101px;
    width: 720px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is IE is rendering the padding/margins differently than Chrome/Firefox (which is usually the issue with layout bugs).

You're best off to specify both `padding` and `margin` when position matters, otherwise you're leaving it up to the browser defaults (which are all different).

You should also make sure your page isn't being loaded into Quirks Mode by IE. Be absolutely sure that you have the proper DOCTYPE definition at the top of your page to force IE to load into standards mode. W3Schools has a good rundown of where and how to use it:

[W3Schools - HTML doctype declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

And then the W3C has a list of all the valid declarations:

[W3C QA - Recommended list of Doctype declarations you can use in your Web document](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

If none of those take care of it, you can create IE version specific CSS and load them using Conditional Comments. That will allow you to specify different values for `top` based for IE.

Comment: @Camran I also added a couple of other things to try.

Comment: Justin: Tell me more about the DOCTYPE... I actually don't even have this on my website... anywhere...

Comment: @Camran - Added two links that should cover DOCTYPE pretty in-depth.

Comment: @Camran - I'm curious... was it a `DOCTYPE` issue or just generic IE `margin`-`padding`-`positioning` madness?

Comment: None of the above actually... It still isn't fixed... Headache

Answer (score 2):

@Camran

Here you go bro I hope this helps you out. http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html Everything is fully detailed and easy to follow along. Trust me I was having that same issue and what kills me is everyone I talked to who claimed they were professionals kept stating that it's an impossibility to have perfect positioning, yet here's somebody who came up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure IE isn't running in quirks mode. This happens when you have any text before the doctype declaration. If its in quirks mode it behaves hideously for CSS. Well moreso than normal.

Comment: How do I check if it is in quirks mode?

Comment: In IE on the page you want to check, erase the URL and type: javascript:alert(document.compatMode) in the address line and hit enter. It should throw a pop up/alert with the info.

Answer (score 0):

Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to target IE and change `top` accordingly.

IMO, that's the ONE thing you need to know to resolve IE issues.

Comment: I think that should be a last resort - in most cases, you should be able to get IE behaving itself w/o writing special cases or resorting to hacks.

Comment: I disagree. The problem is not your code, it is (almost) always IE. Why bother rewriting when you can use CCs, and CC is not a hack IMO, it is an adapted solution for IE.

Comment: Most cases... except `margin`, `padding` and `positioning`. If you find conditional comments distasteful you can also use a variety of tricks in your syntax to write CSS rules which will be interpreted only by specific versions of IE.

Comment: If those tricks involve CSS hacks (star hack, underscore hack, etc.) don't bother. You're only setting yourself up for trouble later.

Comment: @Christopher right, that's why I think conditional comments are cleaner anyway.

Comment: @Soufiane Sorry, I meant for that to be a reply to the comment above mine. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a css reset? (http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) It'll help you make sure all your browsers are starting with the same default padding and margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), and see if that helps. Include it before any other CSS declarations.